# Stretching a Table's Width to fit web browser

Tags: html, html-table, dreamweaver, stretch

I have scoured the internet for a long time trying to solve my problem. I have a table with my whole site in it and would like for it to stretch to fit the user's web browser size.
Here is all the site's code:

```
<body>

<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="525" rowspan="2"><img src="My Images/Speaker.png" width="525" height="772"               
ondragstart="return false" />
    </td>

    <td width="697" height="16">
    *Flash Video Here*
    </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="My Images/Vymil.jpg" width="822" height="597" ondragstart="return false"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any helpful solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Give width in Percentage in `<table>` and `<TD>` tag. This it will set as per browser window size. Give 100% in `<table>` and appropriate percentages to every `<TD>`

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses I've tried the above 2, and still no luck. Harry Joy I know that this is a possible solution I just didnt want to have to delve into percentages anymore wanted to know if there was a simpler solution to make the <TD> tags auto resize due to the parent tables resizing

Comment: @Tech0guy: No its not dependent on parent if you give size without percentage. It will be same for all browser sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<!-- content -->
</table>
```

This will ensure your table will stretch to your browser's size.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9wMU/

Comment: I added a test page for you to show how your code should look.

Comment: @user1385191 thanks for sharing a propert snippet of code, that everyone can relate and understand too!